# Error: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by 'svn://IP.Address'?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, branch, merge

I am trying to merge a Branch to Trunk using the TSVN 'Reintegrate a branch' feature. However I get the following error.

> Error: Retrieval of mergeinfo
>   unsupported by 'svn://IP.Address'?

What is the reason for this error? Also is there some other way to merge the Branch to the Trunk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe the SVN server you're referring to is of a version prior to 1.5?
Or the repository hasn't been updated after updating the server itself?

svn:mergeinfo is used by the merge tracking feature to keep track of which revisions have been merged WRT a file or a directory.

The error message you get seems to indicate a mismatch between your client's svn version and the version installed on the server.

Not sure about your second question. TortoiseSVN itself gives you 3 different possibilities: merge a range of revisions, reintegrate a branch and (I may be wrong here, I'm on Mac right now) merge two different trees.

You should probabily refer to the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) to really understand the difference between

```
svn merge
```

and

> svn merge --reintegrate

Comment: both svn merge and svn merge --reintegrate give me this error. if I must use old SVN repository, does it mean I also must have old client for this to work?

Answer (score 9):

If you are on IntelliJ 13.1 (Build #IU-135.475) and having this problem and your server is not 1.7x yet simply go to your Subversion preferences, presentation tab, un-tick 'Show merge source in history and annotations'.

[SVN: Branch and reintegrate is not working with updated server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720420/svn-branch-and-reintegrate-is-not-working-with-updated-server/17726130#17726130)

Comment: the user didn't even mention, so it's a bit random to give an answer so tied up to a very precise IntelliJ version. Also, this is the same answer you've given on the link you posted. Are you just spamming this everywhere. Same comments apply on that post, no mention of IntelliJ.

Comment: @bitoiu, yet it is helpful for people who are running into IntelliJ issues, and relevant even if not to everyone who reads these answers. SO answers are not just for the person asking, but for others with similar problems.  That's the whole point of SO.

Comment: I read the original question and answer, and this would not pass most review checks, it has 8 votes, it helped some folks, I'm happy with that, but my comment sticks.

Answer (score 1):

Check for server software version (`svnadmin`, `svnserv` or `mod_dav_svn.so`). Upgrade to any >= 1.5.

Next upgrade repository (take few seconds):

```
$ svnadmin upgrade REPOS_PATH
```

If you worry or have no remote access for converting - dump or sync repository copy by:

```
$ svnsync initialize --username=XXX --password=YYY $MIRROR $MASTER
$ svnsync synchronize $MASTER
```

or:

```
 $ svnadmin dump $MASTER  > svn.dump
```

That's all!

Comment: what if I cannot upgrade, because I'm not the owner? is there any workaround?

Comment: In my case the server was up to date but I forgot to execute the "svnadmin upgrade /var/depot/svn" command...

Answer (score 0):

In our case we deactivated the `scm` property: `sonar.scm.disabled=true`. And finally the sonarqube client sent the code to the server.