# SVN: Branch and reintegrate is not working with updated server

Tags: svn, mergeinfo

I am working with a Subversion server that was recently upgraded to version 1.7. I am using the command-line Linux client 1.7.10.

I created a branch like this:

`%: svn copy svn+ssh://acme.com/a/b/c/trunk svn+ssh://acme.com/a/b/c/branches/ovm_sequencer -m "Feature branch for ovm_sequencer"`

After a couple of edits, I tried to reintegrate into the trunk and only ran into problems:

```
%: svn merge --reintegrate '^/c/branches/ovm_sequencer'
svn: E160013: File not found: revision 1677, path '/c/branches/ovm_sequencer'

%: svn merge --reintegrate svn+ssh://acme.com/a/b/c/branches/ovm_sequencer
svn: E200007: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by 'svn+ssh://acme.com/a/b/c/branches/ovm_sequencer'
```

What has gone wrong and how can it be fixed?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/125536/subversion-retrieval-of-mergeinfo-unsupported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two notes:

- `^` in SVN-path means always *repository-root*, thus `^/c/branches/ovm_sequencer` implies "/c/branches/ovm_sequencer" **inside repository**, while you have (most probably) repository in `acme.com/a/b/c` path, and URL must be `^/branches/ovm_sequencer`
- "Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported" means one bad fact about your Network|SVN admin - he doesn't read Release Notes for updated software: in order to have mergeinfo supported on server side except updating software for pre-1.5 Subversion to 1.5 or later, repository also must to be upgraded  in order to have new format. Topic (very old - from 2008 year) on Collabnet ["mergeinfo not supported"](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=110210)

Comment: The first note was very helpful. My URL was actually `^/b/c/branches/ovm_sequencer`. Once I had the syntax right the mergeinfo worked! (I'm not sure if the admin did something else in the meantime.) I suspect SVN wasn't understanding how to parse the two URLs with `svn+ssh:` as being related.

Answer (score 23):

If you are on IntelliJ 13.1 (Build #IU-135.475) and having this problem and your server is not 1.7x yet simply go to your Subversion preferences, presentation tab, un-tick 'Show merge source in history and annotations'.

Comment: 1.7 is not necessary.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17726130/1000655 .  (Commenting because this answer has the most votes, and I wouldn't want folks jumping through a bunch of unnecessary hoops!)

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade remote repository, not personal checkout (take few seconds):

```
$ svnadmin upgrade REPOS_PATH
```

If you worry or have no remote access for converting - dump or sync repository copy by:

```
$ svnsync initialize --username=XXX --password=YYY $MIRROR $MASTER
$ svnsync synchronize $MASTER
```

or:

```
 $ svnadmin dump $MASTER  > svn.dump
```

Comment: what should I put instead of REPOS_PATH?