# How to get SonarQube working with SVN server v1.6.11?

Tags: c++, sonarqube, svn-server, mergeinfo

I'm trying to get SonarQube working for my first project and run into this error message now during analysis of C++ code:

```
E200007: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by 
         'https://para.example.com/repos/app/trunk/src/Botan/botan_version.py'
```

I found [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17726130/115751), but we are running v1.6.11 on our server, not v1.7.

I note that subversion 1.6 does support mergeinfo but perhaps SonarQube is querying using the wrong syntax for v1.6?

How can I get mergeinfo to work with SonarQube v5.2 and SVN plugin v1.2 using svn server v1.6.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually mean your SVN server was not properly migrated. We collected some details on plugin documentation page:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SVN+Plugin

Basically you should try to run `svnadmin upgrade` on your repository (on server side).